# key Error 'data' when loading rdata into python using pyreadr

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

So until now I was able to use the `pyreadr` package to load `rdata` files to `python`. Somehow this time I keep getting a **key error 'data'**

```r
# load the data set:
rdata_read = pyreadr.read_r("/content/GrowthData.rda")

data = rdata_read[ 'data' ]

n = data.shape[0]
```

Where does the error come from ?
Furthermore, I found out that the type of this is a `"collections.OrderedDict"` which is new to me and never happened before. Consequently, I tried to convert it to a `pandas` data frame. Unfortunately, I could not convert this type to a pandas data frame either as I receive the error **"must pass a 2-D array"**. Hence, I am very confused right now and don't know how I can access this data via `python` and work with it. Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Pyreadr read_r function always gives back a OrderedDict (think of it just as a regular python dictionary, the distinction was important in older versions of python, not anymore), where the keys of the dictionary are the name of the object (dataframe) as it was set in R, and the value is the dataframe. You can read about this in the [README](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr#basic-usage-reading-files)

The reason why it returns a dictionary is because in an RData file you can save multiple objects (dataframes), therefore pyreadr has to give a way to return multiple dataframes you can recognize by their name.

In R you would do:

```
save(dataframe1, dataframe2, file="GrowthData.rda")
```

What I would suggest you to do in python, is after you have read the data, explore what keys you have in there:

```
# load the data set:
rdata_read = pyreadr.read_r("/content/GrowthData.rda")
print(rdata_read.keys()) 
# would print dataframe1, dataframe2 in the above example
```

this will tell you what objects have been saved in the Rdata file and you can retrieve as you were doing before

```
data = rdata_read['dataframe1']
```